# Apache James - E-mail is sent but can't fetch

Tags: james

I'm trying to setup a local Apache James mail server to development purposes but it is not working. Here is what I did so far:

1. Installed Apache James (v3.4.0), started service and added a user 'test@localhost'.
2. Setup account on Mozila Thunderbird and sent an e-mail to this address.
3. When I see the log, there is a message that e-mail has been spooled:

   INFO  17:18:25,453 | org.apache.james.smtpserver.SendMailHandler | Successfully spooled mail Mail1582834705410-7098b596-e6ff-4536-90cd-1c27618ef0f0 from MaybeSender{mailAddress=Optional[test@localhost]} on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 for [test@localhost]
4. But I can't fetch any message.

Is there any additional configuration to be done in order to send and fetch emails to/from local email server?

thanks,

Comment: this log is of an outbound mail from the SMTP service. Which message are you trying to fetch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a version problem. Same at me with version 3.4.0. Try with version 3.3.0. It works OK.